# Overriding Parent Theme... will cause plugins failure?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, child-theme

I overrides the parent theme by copying "header.php" and "footer.php" files to the "child" folder, it is working nicely. 
But I wonder if I install a plugin that need to edit the "header.php" or "footer.php" files, what will happen then??  Since I override those php files, will the plugin edit the files in "child" folder as well??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plugin never edits those files - WordPress uses a system of "hooks" and "filters" that allows plugins to change behaviour without altering code.

So, in short, as long as you've created your child theme correctly, plugins will work fine.

Some references:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Comment: Thanks. Actually I purchased the theme from 3rd party, sometimes they may update the theme files and I need to check and update the child files as well. Except this case, do I need to worry any other things??